# Eclipse Milo: Server event generation

Tags: java, eclipse, opc, opc-ua, milo

I am trying to generate events on the OPC server based on the example found in the milo GitHub page and I am unable to figure out how to do it. I can read and write to a node, but I managed to do it mainly due to the provided examples.

Regards,
Eriks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events aren't implemented yet. All I can say as for the timeline is before Milo reaches 1.0.

Comment: Is this still not implemented? Is it possible in Milo to subscribe from client to a server variable and receive event when it is changed? Also, is it possible to use EventNotifier in Milo yet? I found some examples for subscribing to events in client, but no example for server, so I am a bit confused?

Comment: No, it's not implemented in the server yet.